# How does a presented view controller know if it is being presented with animation or not?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

How does `presentedVC` know if it is being presented by:

```
present(presentedVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

or by:

```
present(presentedVC, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

Comment: what you want to achieve ? because if animated is true then there is animation else not!

Comment: @Lion The presented view controller will have an animation after it appears. I wanted it not doing the animation if it is being presented with `animated: false`. Just want to use that parameter so that I don't have that parameter passed from wherever else.

Answer (score 0):

You can take one flag(variable of type bool) in your presented view controller and set it to yes or no before you present that view controller! and you can use that flag everywhere in your presented viewcontroller! that's it!

For example,

```
TestViewController *tvc = [[TestViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"TestViewController" bundle:nil];

tvc.isAnimated = NO;

[self presentViewController:tvc animated:NO completion:nil];
```

**Swift :**

```
    let nvc = NewViewController()
    nvc.isAnimated = false
    self.present(nvc, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

Comment: This will definitely work. I'm probably gonna go this way, but still wanna wait to see if it's possible to get the parameter in `present` call.